# MPMoviePlayerController not playing local video sometimes

Tags: ios, ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am playing a local video file using

```
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
self.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
//customizing the media player properties
self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
self.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
//asking media player to get ready for playback
[self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
```

However the issue is, at times video plays perfectly fine and at times, it doesn't and playback fails with error:

```
 _itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
kind = 1;
new = 2;
old = 0;
}
```

fileURL is the url of file in temp directory.

Please guide me.

PS: I am using iOS 7.1.1

Comment: What is the file you are trying to play? File type and name?

Comment: My file url is:
file:///private/var/mobile/Applications/7AEE28C1-3A23-45F5-B7DD-9489C219792C/tmp/capture4.mp4

Comment: Try NSLog-ing your filename to see if it's correct even during the times your playback fails.

Comment: And is your url structured correctly with 3 backslashes after file:?

Comment: @LyndseyScott it is same during the time playback fails. If I write same video asset library and try to play, it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the video you are trying to play meets the requirements of the iOS platform. iOS supports these industry-standard video formats and compression standards:

- `H.264` video, up to 1.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Low-Complexity version of the `H.264` Baseline Profile with AAC-LC audio up to `160 Kbps`, `48 kHz`, stereo audio in `.m4v`, `.mp4`, and `.mov` file formats
- `H.264` video, up to 768 Kbps, 320 by 240 pixels, 30 frames per second, Baseline Profile up to Level 1.3 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
- `MPEG-4` video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with `AAC-LC` audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats

Your video must be of a one of above-mentioned formats. Otherwise it will not play correctly.

Comment: I dont think, it is the issue of format/industry-standards, because If I write the movie in asset library, it works fine there.